# Getting an error while uploading a code to the Arduino when ethernet shield is attached

Tags: arduino-uno, shields, ethernet

I bought ethernet Shield today and connected it to Arduino Uno, now when I try to upldoad I get the following error, however if I remove the shield from the UNO it works fine.

```
Sketch uses 10,486 bytes (32%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32,256 bytes.
Global variables use 661 bytes (32%) of dynamic memory, leaving 1,387 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2,048 bytes.
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
```

[image: Ethernet is not plugged in]

Is it something wrong with he ethernet shield ?
Ethernet is not plugged in but even when i plug in the ethernet wire the indicators at Jack does not lit up

Comment: Unplug your ethernet shield. Then upload your program. Plug in your ethernet shield  and check if your program is working fine. If your program is not working as expected, there may be some issues with the shield.

Comment: I have tried that already it didn't helped

Comment: What was not working. Your program was not working or you were getting errors uploading code.?

Comment: Error uploading code when shield is plugged in

Comment: Upload the code and then plug in your shield. Then check if your uploaded code is working correct or not.?

Comment: I have tried that already , then nothing comes in serial monitor tried all baud rate

Comment: If you are sure enough that all the connections and your code is correct, that means your shield is not working.

Comment: I learned yesterday late night that it's duminloev shield while I have UNO R3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by cleaning the soldering near the SD card slot on ISCP, see image below.

[image]